# DrawLines very slow when lines are crossing each other

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing

For large number of lines `n` > 1000 the performance of [Graphics.DrawLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawlines) is very poor (multiple seconds) when the lines are crossing each other. See the following example:

```
private static readonly Random r = new Random();

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int n = 10000;
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1))
    {
        Point[] points = new Point[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int ii = i * 1000 / n;
            int x = r.Next(0, 1001);
            int y = r.Next(0, 1001);
            points[i] = new Point(x, y);
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, points);
    }
}
```

When I replace `x` or `y` by `ii` the performance is good. Here the lines are not crossing each other.

I observed as well that the line width has an impact. Line widths larger than 1 are even slower.

Is there any way to improved the performance of `DrawLines`?

Comment: The Form must be DoubleBuffered. The `Random` object should be declared as a `static` Field (outside the handler).  `Pen` is disposable. `r.Next(0, 1000)` goes from `0` to `999`.

Comment: It's not slower because the lines are crossing - it's slower because the number of pixels being drawn is much higher if you randomly add points in the range 0 .. 1000. If you use `ii` for X or Y you're only incrementing the coordinate.

Comment: @Jimi I've updated my code according to your comments. Thanks.. If I turn on `DoubleBuffered` it's much faster for `LineWidth` equals to 1. For larger widths it's still very slow.

Comment: Use `Graphics.DrawLine()` instead, randomizing 2 `PointF` positions per iteration. That's much faster. Random must be a Field.

Comment: @Jimi When I use `for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, points[i - 1], points[i]);` it's much faster even with larger line widths. Thanks. But I'm using National Instruments `ScatterPlot` to generate a Cartesian plot. And this `ScatterPlot` calls the `Graphics.DrawLines` method and not the `Graphics.DrawLine` method. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Do you need to use this library to draw the lines, or do you have means to just get the collection of points it generates?

Comment: @Jimi I need this library to plot my measurement data.

Comment: If that's the case, you need to reduce the number of points you feed to the drawing method to ~1/4 of what you're using now (i.e., below 2500).

Comment: @Jimi That's not an option.

Comment: Another possibility is to draw to a [BufferedGraphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bufferedgraphics) and perform double-buffering yourself. Implies drawing off-screen with correct timings. It may get a little complex if you have not done this before.

Answer (score 0):

As Matthew Watson points out, the most probable reason is simply that you are drawing more pixels. If you change your code to

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 4)
{
    points[i] = new Point(0, 0);
    points[i+1] = new Point(1000, 1000);
    points[i+2] = new Point(1000, 0);
    points[i+3] = new Point(0, 1000);
}
```

You would repeatedly be drawing a cross. When I test this I get about 230ms for drawing a line strip of 10k segments to a bitmap. And that seem to be perfectly within expectations. I would expect you to get similar performance when drawing to screen using double buffering.

When drawing random points there seem be a performance degradation sometimes, especially when using wider lines. My only explanation for this is that it hits some edge case that is handled much less efficiently. I would recommend seeing if you get acceptable performance with actual data, and make another post with said data if performance is much worse than expected.

You might also want to take a look at [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) or [Visvalingam–Whyatt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visvalingam%E2%80%93Whyatt_algorithm) to simplify your line. If this is a plot it might not make much sense to have many more points than you have pixels on your monitor.

Comment: I saw this problem when I measured noise in the complex plane (with Vector Network Analyzer, CW Sweep Mode) and I wanted to plot it as an Cartesian plot. Then I tried to come up with a minimal example. And noise is random.

Comment: @Wollmich but is it useful to draw *lines* between random points? When testing, the performance issue with wider lines seem to be avoided by calling g.DrawLine repeatedly, so perhaps some issue with drawing the joining between lines?

Comment: Finally I decided to plot only points and no lines when I have noise data.